# On Jobs, how do I sort by most recent matches?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

It appears that I have two options to filters jobs: Matches and Most Recent.

If I select "Most Recent", it sort mostly by the newest first. The very first posting is not the most recent, but it is featured, so I assume that's intentional.

[image: Most Recent Jobs]

---

However, if I search by "Matches", the job posting times are ordered more randomly.

[image: Matches search]

In this search, we have posts that are a week old, then a month, then 6 days, then a week. If I keep scrolling I have 2 weeks, 3 weeks, 2 weeks, 1 week.

How do I order by matches by newest?

---

After using this for a few weeks, my matches have the following order, sorted by how long ago they were posted:

```
1 week, 
2 hours, 
1 week, 
yesterday, 
2 days, 
2 hours, 
6 days, 
4 weeks, 
4 days, 
6 days, 
1 week, 
4 weeks, 
2 weeks, 
3 weeks, 
3 days, 
4 weeks, 
3 days, 
3 weeks, 
2 weeks, 
4 days, 
4 weeks, 
2 weeks, 
4 days, 
4 weeks, 
yesterday, 
6 days
```

This sort order makes no sense. Why is something that was posted yesterday second to last? Why are listings that are hours old scattered in the first few results and why do I have 4 week old listings bumping things that are newer?

The usability for finding matches isn't helpful if it's showing me older results that I've (presumably seen already) before brand new matches.

Answer (score -1):

Matches is a recommendation algorithm where one of the features included is recency (other features include your [personalized prediction data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data), and tags from your CV).  There is no newest sort available for the matches tab.  If it's new and relevant, then it will surface towards the top.

Also your assumption is correct on the "most recent" tab.  That's by design.
Edit: We will be taking into consideration adding a sort order to the matches tab.

Comment: Would it be possible to reconsider this? I think ordering by most recent is important - especially if I've looked for positions recently (last week or so). I'd want to see the newest ones toward the top. As a user, I'd expect "matches" to do everything you mentioned *except* account for when the position was posted. To me, that doesn't matter. A position can match my needs for "great job" regardless of it being posted 6-8 minutes ago or 6-8 weeks ago. By sorting them this way, it's much harder for me to determine what I have and have not already looked at.

Comment: For users who check for new jobs regularly, the recency of a job is important to determine how interesting it is. This is why the publishing date is one of the factors that come into play in the "matches" algorithm. We need a way to personalize it by user, so that depending on the date of your last visit we can show you "new" listings; we're not there just yet.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you at telling me @AurélienGasser. Are you saying that newest postings *should* appear first?

Comment: Based on [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312553/189134), I really want to request that sort order be considered. If you are limiting matches to a single page, I'm going to lose out on jobs I find interesting if I take a day or two to consider applying. Consider this: I see a job today that I like. With the holidays coming up, I delay putting in an application with the assumption that the job will be available in two weeks still. I do not bookmark the job. In two weeks I return and I have new matches that more clearly reflect my tags, but aren't what I'm looking for. [cont]

Comment: The two things I didn't do - bookmark and apply immediately - have bitten me in this case. If the job still exists, it's buried under two weeks of "Most Recent" jobs. It *did* match my tags at one point though, so I should be able to go through a listing of those matches to find it still. I can't do that, if there are new matches that have bumped this one off the one page of results.

Comment: In the current implementation, the matches tab sorts results based on different criteria including publishing date, distance and tag matches (among others.) Hence newest jobs have a *higher chance* of being near the top. The use case you bring up is very interesting and we'll keep it in mind when thinking of possible improvements

Comment: @Will Cole - I cannot honestly upvote this answer to the end user this is very confusing.  If it requires me to think and understand some internal details this issue will be posted over and over again because it simply is too ambiguous.

Comment: Having used this for a couple weeks now, I'd like to again request this be reconsidered. Not having the ability to sort my matches by how recent it is, means my current results are in the following order: 1 week, 2 hours, 1 week, yesterday, 2 days, 2 hours, 6 days, 4 weeks, 4 days, 6 days, 1 week, 4 weeks, 2 weeks, 3 weeks, 3 days, 4 weeks, 3 days, 3 weeks, 2 weeks, 4 days, 4 weeks, 2 weeks, 4 days, 4 weeks, yesterday, 6 days.

Comment: This makes no sense. There are brand new postings at the bottom of my search (notice the "yesterday" is second to last). This isn't usable. I shouldn't need to scroll through the entire list to see if anything is new. I agree they are "relevant", but something that is 4 weeks old is less relevant than something that was posted yesterday.

Comment: This seems like a very easy fix to implement.