# Fresh jobs link needs some sort of tooltip

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

What exactly does this link do?

[image]

I know it shows additional jobs and the page refreshes but can someone tooltip this?

Comment: Tooltip is a verb now? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the "matches" tab there, which caps out at one page. That "fresh" link just takes you to the "most recent" tab.

Comment: But how many people are going to know that?  A simple tool tip will clear this up for end users.  When I read fresh jobs I thought it meant that it was going to show me the most recent job postings.

Comment: @JonH Maybe that link needs to be clearer in general. Utilizing a tooltip can be an indicator that we're not being as clear with our calls to action, prompts, or labeling. Perhaps the wording should be, "There are no more job matches available at this time. Click here to view recently added jobs."

Comment: @Hynes - I agree with your comment, to me it currently is ambiguous, what are fresh jobs?

Comment: @JonH Exactly. It's attempt at personality. Unfortunately it falls flat and fails to communicate the basic message: you've reached the end of this list but there are other jobs you can view sorted by recency. Click here to view them.