# What exactly is most recent given days are ranked lower

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On the jobs listing page if I sort by most recent for a **specific company** then I was hoping the results would show up based on most recent number of days, followed by weeks, months, etc.

But this appears to be pretty random:

[image]

Comment: Related (see the answer and my comments on it): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312540/189134, it may have something to do with the "relevance"?

Comment: @Andy - This is very confusing to the end user.  End users don't care about algorithms.  If I'm sorting by most recent I expect to see jobs based on days from most recent to the oldest.

Comment: I agree with you completely.

Comment: Sorry this stuff frustrates me...I mean who is really guiding this type of development.  It seems to be random stuff that just doesn't make sense, I don't get it.

Comment: Looking at it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've temporarily switched off the caching here as it's causing more problems than just this and we'll be looking into how we fix it up longer term. Marking the question as status-completed for now!

Answer (score 4):

The issue has been mitigated for now, the results should now be correct.

The underlying issue has to do with cache invalidation, we'll be working on it.

Thank you for your report!

Comment: what exactly would you guys be caching in a sort like this, I'm very curious because I would think this type of sort is NOT cached.

Comment: We're caching the running jobs details. Here, a job has just been re-published, and its "age" was not updated correctly in cache, leading to the wrong order of jobs

Comment: Yikes, that could easily bite you.  You'd have to cache almost every new changes I don't know if its worth it.

Comment: Yep that's a tricky issue indeed!

Comment: this is still not working correctly.

Comment: @JonH I've temporarily switched off the caching here as it's causing more problems than just this and we'll be looking into how we fix it up longer term. Marking the question as [tag:status-completed] for now.

Comment: Dean I'd post that as an answer for now so I can close this.