# Help us Redesign Job Ads

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

You know the little blue/orange/occasionally-other-colors box where we advertise Jobs on Stack Overflow?

[image]

Aren't they beautiful? Don't you love their design? We love them like a mother would love her... neighbor's ugly child... and it sure has been fun hanging out with them, but perhaps it's time to go.

The reality is, we've never spent much design time on these, and it shows. Not only could the aesthetics be improved, but we think there's potential to improve their utility by altering what information we present, and how we present it. So, with the recent [change in sidebar size](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites), we think it's finally time to give them some love. Well, not *these* ads, they're ugly, and love ain't gonna solve that, but we *can* get newer prettier ads and love them instead!

## Tell us Your Ideas

We're just barely getting started with ideas internally, but we wanted to simultaneously open up the floor to ideas from the community, rather than waiting until we're done and asking for feedback.

So now is your chance to tell us: What factors into your decision to click or not click on an ad? What kinds of information are most important to you? Do you have any anecdotes on how you select jobs to apply for? Besides individual job listings, are there other types of ads for the job board that you would find interesting? Other ideas or comments?

#### Details

- We have to design for both 300x250px and 300x500px "creative" sizes.
- All of our basic ad rules will apply: nothing super obnoxious, no animated ads, no hover actions, etc.
- We're looking to design more than one replacement ad. We'll start with gut feelings, then A/B test various ideas to see which ones are effective.
- This isn't a design competition, though you are free to submit images if it helps you express your ideas. We might use them as inspiration.

> We're *not* looking for feedback on how we could give you more individual control over the ads you see, or to stop seeing job ads entirely if you're truly not interested. Honestly, we *really* want to do that, and it will happen, but for the moment, let's keep this on topic.

## Our Initial Ideas

A few basic ideas we're already throwing around. Feel free to comment or expand on them.

- Display a single job per ad, but with more information about the job/company, and perhaps images.
- Display a single job, but make the ad interactive where you could swipe through multiple listings.
- Create themed ads for specific geographies with lots of jobs, like New York and London.
- Creatives which don't advertise specific jobs, but instead advertise how many jobs we have in a particular tech stack in a particular location, perhaps highlighting how many were posted recently.

For reference, I've put together two documents which contain:

- [A list of the data we *could* include in ads](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mv376LJkI3yEa7E5JQLWhrESoWMvt8viUMTtbS0a6mI/edit?usp=sharing)
- [What the ads have looked like historically](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bDqaM0uc2quIu5K_InkfWbukP_-n90GG67TWt6WAM5Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: -1 circle is blue, not red. I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Will the redesign be complete in 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: I like to see the [yellow "Remote" wifi-like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dygV4.png) symbol for remote jobs even in the ad space. Not sure if it is already implemented. :/

Comment: @BhargavRao the real question is: will it ever ship?

Comment: @BhargavRao not exactly, but we've done specific remote-work ads. Indicating whether the job offers remote would definitely be something useful to display more prominently.

Comment: @BhargavRao feel free to add any ideas as an answer.

Comment: Perhaps a more effective use of space like a scrolling `<marquee>`?

Comment: @meagar we would love to, of course, but sadly [marquee has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee), so we can't depend on it working in all browsers.

Comment: @BretCopeland Then what about making sure every ad has the salary clearly highlighted with a `<blink>` tag?

Comment: @meagar You jest, but that would **greatly** improve job posting quality and helpfulness.

Comment: @meagar No need for `<blink>` so long as you outline the salary with a freehand red circle.

Comment: @meagar don't you mean the `<bling>` tag?

Comment: Actually `<blink>` has [even more red boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink), and even some nested yellow-in-red boxes, it must be *extra* deprecated. Never mind, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @BretCopeland it's only <bling> if the pay is denominated in gold.

Comment: How about working on more important topics such as how to drive employers to update candidates on whether a job was filled or not. I applied to some places back in December and I'm still in limbo. Much more important fires happening that need putting out before this.

Comment: I tend to be a bit more visual so I feel like maybe adding a logo of the company would help (although idk if you would have to pay fees and what not for its usage) just a wild idea. And this is just my opinion

Comment: Yes @JonH, I'll get our graphic designers on that problem right away.

Comment: @JustDoIt we wouldn't go out and get a company's logo. They'd submit them to us for use (as many already do), so we'd be using them with their permission, just like how advertising works in general.

Comment: @JonH if you want a more serious response, there are already people working on the problem you mentioned. It's a difficult problem, but not one that I, or the designer working on this, would have been allocated to. Furthermore, improving the ads which drive users to the job board _is_ a priority for us, even if it's not your personal top priority. Luckily we can work on more than one thing at a time.

Comment: May sound stupid, but I like them pretty much the way they are. +1 for some simple paging, -1 for decreasing number of jobs, -1 for logos or custom artwork, +1 for small icons (greyscale would be enough). A _don't show this job again_ feature might make sense. Maybe info about primary language of communication. Maybe a user setting for preferred region (currently it is based on the IP(?), which often isn't what one might want if traveling a lot), maybe a user setting for _has to contain tag_ or _has to be remote_.

Comment: Being a **padawan developer**, aka Junior Developer with not a lot of experience under my belt, it would be great to see only those ads that require junior devs, or internship positions. 90% of the ads I see are for Seniors.

Comment: @Granola doesn't mean you can't apply for them... I've had luck in the past (not through this site) via applying for more senior jobs than my title would allow. Maybe only show senior positions that in a pinch would settle for less experience?

Comment: Location, location, location (for me). Or remote.

Comment: Simple idea to improve it: I'm from Belgium, show me job offers from Belgium, not Netherlands or France or Germany! Maybe then I'd actually consider clicking on them.

Comment: Just out of further curiosity, why is there such a commitment to this jobs section ? It's useful for an extremely small percentage of people here, if even. So I'm just curious why so much effort is going into this. If it's financial reasons that would make sense, but you guys might be just making things more cluttered than they need to be. (I'm happy to be completely wrong on the demand topic too!)

Comment: Why does it matter how it looks? In the ad-spammed jungle that is the internet, you quickly develop an ability to completely ignore advertising. I don't recall every casting a second glance at that advert after seeing it for the first time. At that first time, it suggested to me that I would be interested in jobs 600km from where I live. Since then I have given it the attention it deserves. Right now it is apparently suggesting a job which would force me to move 300km. Steady improvement!

Comment: if I hadn't have a job I wouldn't be surfing Stackoverflow :D

Comment: Maybe the jobs can be related to the tags that are you seeing in that precise moment, and not just for historical. And most important, configuration, the "jobs hunt" webs work so well because it allows the users configure what they are looking for, no one better than you know that(...ads have impressme some times though..) this is not a jobs seekers website, but some minors configuration options would be better. My opinion.

Comment: add a little number that says "how many people have applied". Add a little date that says "posted when"

Comment: Just for a mini ego boost, I'd like to see "Jobs looking for you:" instead of "Looking for a job?"

Comment: @Pogrindis if you read the SO developer survey, most of us are not deleriously happy at our jobs. SE wants to help us find jobs that will make us deleriously happy, and make some dollars in the process.

Comment: Maybe with the help of some creative icons / badges for the languages and roles displayed could be more eye catchy. Also, the adds could be related with your most active topics, location or based on previous searches. Add a "warn me about" option to get notifications about available opportunities. Open a "create a job add" contest for creatives and offer the change of bragging rights for the winner(s) on StackOverflow, this could spice things a bit

Comment: Your links are blocked by our corporate proxy. I'm sure this affects many others here...

Comment: "...but we wanted to simultaneously open up the floor to ideas from the community, rather than waiting until we're done and asking for feedback". What a great idea; did you guys come up with that all on your own? ;)

Comment: I would like to see some keywords highlighted, like offer relocation

Comment: I would prefer if there is some setting/preference somewhere, where I can say, that I am looking for a job with these parameters, and in these cities. For example, I keep seeing jobs for the city I live in, but doesn't mean I am not open to other cities, and as I am planning to shift, the ads are of no use to me as of now and I would like them to be useful, especially now, since I have to look for a job soon. So unfortunate this is!!!

Comment: Perhaps I am the only one that thinks so - but I am fond of the current system. It could do with more information about the job, such as salary. The current system shows me "what", "who" and "where". That's all I really need to know. If those match, I can look at their posting page to see if their culture matches.

Comment: An `<apply>` link so you can apply right now to the job of your dreams.

Comment: Include the Joel Test Score next to each offer (when applicable)

Comment: Allow me to tell you guys what company I work for so I stop seeing job ads from my company.

Comment: If the jobs adverts I see there are not relevant to my interests, UI matters less to me

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava we don't disagree with that. UI and targeting are somewhat orthogonal concerns, and one isn't intended to be a substitute for the other.

Comment: @BretCopeland Good then what about if I am not interested in senior positions? That would filter out many jobs I am not interested to see. Commenting here, as there are many answers.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava right now, how user preferences work, as it relates to jobs, is a moving target due to unification of SO and Careers. When that settles down we'll be able to work on adding more control for the types of ads you want to see. That's why I said we weren't looking for feedback on "more control" features at the moment, even though we do plan to work on them in the future.

Comment: @BretCopeland I see well then you can just add icon on UI, whether this is Senior, Mid, or Junior position. This is my suggestion, just posted here as already there are many answers.

Comment: Maybe http://ux.stackexchange.com/ is better place to ask :-)

Comment: Make them more relevant or allow me to vote on how relevant the ad is for me. For instance, this link http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/104472/full-stack-software-engineer-synthetics-new-relic?searchTerm=python&offset=2&distanceunits=Miles&location=arizona&range=20 shows up because I'm interested in python. However, after clicking I found this line "(but, to be honest, we mainly use Java)". This wastes my time.  I'd like to be able to upvote, downvote, and comment on ads.

Comment: @Bret, You guys are awesome; I see the top two answers already implemented! You could've added [status-completed] above those answers (like in a few other questions of the same kind). Anyway, Great Job and Keep the good work going. Thanks again.

Answer (score 200):

> What factors into your decision to click or not click on an ad?

I like to see a salary range that is in a range I'm interested in. Since I work full time I don't really have time for ads that don't answer this basic question.

Comment: money is not everything sometimes....company reputation, location, skillet etc. when someone REALLY wants to find a new job they will pay attention to every related AD they see.

Comment: I agree its not everything that why a range is nice so I can see oh these guys think there range is a lot less then I currently make so obviously commuting further probably isn't going to work.  Also when I'm browsing stack overflow unless I'm specifically in careers I'm not REALLY looking at that point but if I saw a list that had a nice salary related to my skill I might be tempted to check it out.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing. Salary range or the ad is as good as blocked to me.

Comment: +1. Salary range and location if it requires physical presence (otherwise just say *remote*). Company reputation is mostly used to estimate the salary range or benefits. The rest can be provided after the click.

Comment: @user2404597 money is not everything, but it IS an incentive. And most developers are not actively looking for a new job, so Stackoverflow has to consider that and provide information that makes these people click job ads.

Comment: I agree that this is crucial, and though I know this won't be easy, I think it would be very helpful if salary was given not as an absolute number, or range, but instead as some sort of index that (semi-) objectively reflects the level of buying power that the compensation would have at the location where the job is. - Just an idea.

Comment: This is something that constantly me about the careers page. I've seen some postings list a salary or salary range though. I think it is an optional thing for the hiring company to list on the page. Although it would behoove  them to list this information more readily, it seems most companies are put off by the idea. It means they get fewer irrelevant contacts and interviews though.

Comment: Ah... jobs, I see those postings everywh.... wait, a job paying $30k more and it's in my town? Huh... I'm curious. *click*

Comment: Well said!!!!....

Comment: Was going to post this too. I know many ads don't put a salary (or even a range), but if it were displayed, I think the data would show more candidates click job listings that show me the money. Which would hopefully entice more employers to reveal the salary in the first place. I'm "has job but is interested" -- so interest me.

Comment: Seems a bit like a cultural thing. Where I'm from, you would only post salary ranges for no-qualifications-needed jobs, such as phone sales or flipping burgers. Setting a salary range for qualified jobs such as programmer would mean no room for negotiation, and also indicate that the company is as serious as a phone sales company.

Comment: Very much this. I have a job already. I am not going to even look at anything that's say, <90% of my current salary locally, and <110% of my salary if I'll need to relocate. However awesome your job is - I can't afford much of a pay cut, because I have bills to pay. This also loosely correlates with desired skill and expertise, so lets me discard the 'entry level' stuff quickly.

Comment: @Lundin The problem is that it turns into a guessing game. Did I ask for too much? Too little? Asking for too much then backtracking because the company wants to pay lower looks bad, and so on. It's an unnecessary complication, and wastes everyones time applying and interviewing to find out the unspeakable secret of a salary. Seems childish to me, just say what you can afford and then everyone knows the score.

Comment: In some companys the salary depends very much the applicant's skilllevel, so the will not been able to give a meaningfull salary range. (I am from germay and talk about smaller companies (<100 emploies), I do not know how this is in the US with big companies)

Comment: I would be willing to tell SO my current salary and location to filter out job offers that weren't of comparable (95%) or greater buying-power. That way job posters don't need to tell potential applicants the salary, but you can be sure that the salary is equivalent to at least what you're making now.

Answer (score 169):

The jobs page listing adds a lot more helpful features like *Remote*, *offers VISA sponsorship*, etc.

[image]

This motivates a few of us to actually look more into those jobs. The sidebar could perhaps add these features. A small Wifi Symbol could refer to remote (with a tool tip)

Something like

[image]

Comment: Love this idea. I think symbols are the best way to go -- I have seen other sites use then as well. Wifi for remote, house for relocation, dollar-sign for equity... (not sure about Visa though). **Only concern** -- a tooltip requires hovering, which OP listed as a no-no.

Comment: @onebree A tooltip on the icons would be a much better user experience, allowing the user to understand the ad details much quicker (They might not always associate a "wifi" icon with "work remotely"). I would argue that tooltips should be excluded from the "no hover actions" request.

Answer (score 156):

Gonna throw an idea out that I'm not sure is a good one.

#### For a single job ad, a "why this was shown"-line

Something Amazon-esque, like:

[image: crummy mockup]

Rather than highlight a single tag (and maybe display more than one tag, or include geo - assuming those are big contributors to why the ad was shown).

Not sure if folks like those explanations though.

Comment: I noticed "Recommended" apps on the Google Play Store do this- I find it helpful, actually, to see if I really am interested in that app or not. (For instance, if it's recommended due to an app I used once and never touched again, I might not want to download that app. But if it's related to my most-used/favorite app, I'm more likely to check it out. Could be similar with tags/techs on SO.)

Comment: Amazon goes as far as letting you remove stuff from your history so you won't see suggestions based on it anymore. Could be applicable here down the line (e.g. I answer PHP questions sometimes but dear lord do not show me PHP jobs)

Comment: Why not put that in the title. instead of hiding it ? I.e. "Looking for a [javascript] job ?". 300px width available, after all, so use it for important things.

Comment: What about jobs that are completely unrelated to my SO activity and experience?:)

Comment: @MSalters we have ads like that, and they do perform better than normal ads.  I put it in the bottom so we'd have more space to explain _why_ - "Looking for [tag] job?" implies we chose it because of your javascript question views, but it doesn't really state that unambiguously.  (Also space gets tight if there's 2 or more factors that mattered)

Comment: @abbyhairboat we have rudimentary support for that right now, although it's not quite as fine-grained. Currently if you have a "disliked" tag in your Careers/Jobs profile, we don't show you jobs that have that tag.

Comment: @abbyhairboat consider this my second upvote for your comment.

Comment: @rossipedia awesome - the tag level is pretty much exactly the level of granularity I would have imagined. You guys are five steps ahead of me (as usual) :)

Answer (score 144):

Could we have a *Not interested ...* with a follow-on of why offering options such as:

- Pay range.
- Too far from ...
- I hate this company
- I wouldn't work in London - ever
- Etc.

This way you can help **me** not be distracted by ads that I will not be interested in at all.

Comment: Thisthisthis.  How the box looks is a minor concern to me, compared to whether I'm interested in the job.

Comment: "Already checked, don't show me again" <-- need to have an option like this. Must only be available if you actually clicked on the link at least once.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but "We're _not_ looking for feedback on how we could give you more individual control over the ads you see, or to stop seeing job ads entirely if you're truly not interested. Honestly, we _really_ want to do that, and it will happen, but for the moment, let's keep this on topic." We have shifting and changing backend infrastructure which would make it difficult to implement these "more control" features at the moment, but when that settles down, you can expect to start to see them.

Comment: @BretCopeland "Give me more control" seems pretty on target for "Help us Redesign Job Ads" and "Tell us Your Ideas"...

Comment: @JoshuaDrake and yet, still out of scope for the feedback we're looking for right now. I haven't heard any "more control" features in this thread that I haven't heard before, or suggested myself, many times. However, I'm genuinely learning things from the people discussing design. We'll get to control issues when unification settles down, and sources of data stop moving so much. In the meantime, we're discussing design because it's something we can do right now.

Comment: @BretCopeland Surely design is derived from requirements.

Comment: @BretCopeland: It's just a matter of priorities whether you want to work on "design" (help you) or "control" (help us). There are requests on Meta.SE from a year ago. That's something you could have worked on for a long time already... Anyway, *you*'ll get what *you* want, which is why I don't like SO so much anymore. Think of giving back to the community from time to time...

Answer (score 82):

My concept is using material design job search ads, we can change the color if needed, this is just default template from me.

X button in the right is the button to close the ads if someone not interest with the ads and automatically show the new ads

300x250 Option:

[image]

300x500 Option:

[image]

Comment: I really like the layout, great job! I would probably add icons mentioned elsewhere to show about company benefits like working remote etc. This could remove the mostly unnecessary date field.

Comment: Thanks, X button in the right is the button to close the ads if someone not interest with the ads and automatically show the new ads

Comment: add remote / salary / whatever additional thinks the company offers icons on a row under the languages / skills required, and i'm in :P

Comment: Could you post a 300x500 or 300x200 image, so we can see how everything scales?

Comment: @RizkyAriestiyansyah with the X button, maybe a "next" symbol would be good. If I close an ad, I expect it to be gone, not be replaced by another. But a loop-icon (or something) could help convey "show more ads"

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.  I would be tempted to click the x button every time I came to the page, until the add(s) disappeared. :) *<major waste of time>*

Comment: I redesigned your answer with icons instead of the calendar thing - see [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315505/help-us-redesign-job-ads/315581#315581)

Comment: @onebree I think instead of a next symbol the X button works. But maybe show that this add is on a stack of ad's (stack of cards) so that you know when you exit out of this one the next one will pop up.

Comment: @RizkyAriestiyansyah could you please post images that are 300x500 and 300x250?

Comment: I just update the image with 300x250 and 300x500 option

Comment: I would say that black color is too sharp and takes the attention away. I would vote for making them grey, e.g. as the background of the button “Add Comment” here.

Comment: @mudasobwa like your request, what do you think?

Comment: Using material design would be awesome, especially if you can use colors that represent an employer's brand. +1

Comment: Beautiful, but 1) holy wow too much orange and 2) I'm guessing SO is going to want to use their branding on tags for the jobs.

Answer (score 67):

Some ideas, some of them inspired by or taken from other answers, with a mockup of what I'm thinking.

- **Single job per ad**
  This probably helps that job get more attention, since you can bring in more information about it and still not overload the user (since you're only showing one lot of a lot of information, instead of three at once). The rest of these ideas are based on this assumption.
- **Include informational icons**
  There are informational icons all over Jobs, such as those that indicate visa sponsorship, remote and relocation options. Those could be included in the job ad.
- **Use a background image**
  Give companies the option to submit a background image to go on their job ad; if they don't, you could default to using the company image.
- **Show the sector**
  Sort of comes under *informational icons*, but I wanted to mention this specifically. Each job appears to have a busines sector associated with it (retail, tech etc): show this on the ad.

Using the above ideas, an ad size of 300x250, and [this job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/102968/product-manager-stack-overflow), I've got this ad:

[image]

The colours could use some work, and you'd probably want it in a sort of "here are jobs" section because otherwise it's not *immediately* obvious what it's advertising - but you get my point. That's what I'm thinking.

Comment: I kinda like the idea of a background image but if one is used I would opt for some type of watermark that lets me know it is a recommendation from careers/jobs - as otherwise one might ignore it as a regular ad.

Comment: @JGreenwell That's a good idea, though it doesn't have to be the background image. I'll have an experiment with that tomorrow.

Comment: I don't read adverts with background images. Supplementary images are fine, but my eyes just glaze over text-on-image-with-more-than-three-colours like oil on water.

Comment: I think ads that show a sense of whimsy are good. so this stuffed toy is a good example.  Encourage advertisers to point out something that makes their DNA. If they are serious but there's something cool about them, make that image be about whatever makes them great.

Comment: Like @veedrac mentions, as *pretty* as the ad is, I'm worried it'd cause banner blindness...

Comment: @KiraCrafter you double-typed the same thing. (or pasted twice, or something :)) May I suggest you delete and re-post with only one of the same thing?  :)  Or a mod could edit it it one sees this first...

Comment: @ArtOfCode Could you make the image transparent / washed out so that it's less in your face?

Comment: It´s not a bad idea, but in a website that has almost no image, I wouldn´t like ads that prominent, it would be annoying i think...it would be less agressive use simbols and no background...that´s my opinion though.

Comment: @Tim how's that for you?

Comment: @JGreenwell how's that for you?

Comment: I would be in favor of this, if an option to opt-out of image ads is also added

Comment: @ArtOfCode better... It's a little grey, but much nicer :) +1

Comment: @Tim I had to make it transparent to a background white to fade the image, then overlay with a transparent black to make the white text visible. That's where the grey's from.

Comment: I love that the current ads are *only* text and icons. Please, no "come drink our Kool Aid" marketing photos. You know the ones I mean, featuring a disingenuously diverse group of professional models standing around an artisan steampunk Keurig machine in the middle of an open floor plan with amazing natural lighting, holding NES controllers or ping pong paddles and laughing. They're always laughing. What are they always laughing at?

Comment: On the other hand, if employers were forced to create hand-drawn MS Paint background images, clicks would go through the roof. [There's precedent!](https://www.reddit.com/r/ads/top/?sort=top&t=all)

Comment: @Veedrac That was insanely genius observation. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 54):

I'd like to see the **salary range** directly in the ad.

For me, it became a **distinguishing factor** about which kind of developer the company is looking for.
If it is in the **low salary range** for that area, I assume they want a programmer with **not much experience or knowledge**.
Consequently, if it is in the **high salary range** for that area, I assume they are looking for more **advanced developers**.

Therefore, having the salary range in the ad would do 2 things:
1. Help me ignore uninteresting job ads and focus more on the interesting ones
2. Motivate job posters to include the salary

Comment: And if it's remote, convert the salary to my currency :)

Comment: @Benjol , very good suggestion , +1 , SO people could use some open web api currency conversion and as geo-ip decoding can help

Answer (score 43):

It would be interesting to display an approximate age for the job listing (either when it was posted or when it was last updated). Maybe this could be a whole ad unit ("New [whatever] jobs this week"), or maybe recent(ly updated) jobs could be called out visually within a normal ad. There's something appealing about getting your application in early rather than hoping that a job listing that hasn't been touched in more than 30 days is still open and applications are still being reviewed.

Comment: Would that result in employers deleting and re-posting their listings (or bumping with edits) to get more ad impressions?  I think the latter concern -- stale listings -- is something you need to solve in some other way, by encouraging employers to update listing status, not by giving employers an incentive for fake activity.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - well, in that case employers could have a "bump" button to show the ad's not stale.

Comment: Or maybe the employer would be required to reassure every two weeks that the position still needs to be filled. Otherwise it goes into kind of "sleep mode".

Comment: If the employer deletes and re-posts at least it shows that they are still looking for applications.

Answer (score 36):

i'm not sure is it possible or not but i think it should be rtl support with a better fonts !

[image]

Comment: Woah - That's not English!

Comment: Showing individual job ads instead of a list of jobs would make it easier to support language-specific options, like RTL text and font options. It's one of many motivations to go in that direction.

Answer (score 34):

> What factors into your decision to click or not click on an ad?

1. Am I at work? No way am I going to go browsing job ads when I'm at work, unless they're for completely irrelevant jobs everyone knows I'm not interested in. Of course, when I use SO at work, I'm most likely looking at questions about technologies I'm stuck with now; at home, I'm more likely to be looking at questions about technologies I want to use. How true that is is probably correlated with how likely I am to be open to a new job in the first place.
2. Is it for the job I already have? My company advertises on SO and I find this advert in particular very disturbing. It tries to sell me a job here, on the basis that I'll be working with great people such as me.

[image: Existing SO job ad]

> What kinds of information are most important to you?

The single most important thing is whether the company is actually interested in hiring. I'm not interested in an employer who will want me to do a day's unpaid work for them before they'll even have a human reply to my email. I'm not interested in an employer who says they'd love to interview me but stops responding as soon as I try to set a date. (Both of these have been outcomes of applying to jobs on SO.)

The thing you are trying to replace is a market for lemons. If I click a job ad, I have a very small chance of actually getting a job out of it: not because I'm unhireable, but because the company is looking for someone entirely different from what they said, or they don't actually have budget to hire someone, or they are hiring in the US and not offering visa sponsorship, or any number of avoidable reasons. Giving me more confidence that the outcome will be either a job offer or a rejection would encourage me to take part.

Other than that, I think the information on the current ads is about right: who the company is, what field the work is in, where they're hiring for.

Comment: Wow.  +1 for the first point.  ... And the second ... And the third... hmm.  If they could implement that first point especially, that would be a major upgrade.  100% Agree.

Comment: Add upvotes and downvotes for employers from real SO people, who applied. Maybe split by job relevance, application process, speed of response etc. Should be able to only vote once per company, per person. Must have 1000 reputation on SO, to prevent abuse. Perhaps, remove votes older than 1yr, to let companies fix their problems and give a fresh start. Then see who remains on top. +1

Comment: First off, that "who you'll work with" where everyone one has stock "avatar missing" images looks terrible, so we're going to get rid of that. It seems like a pretty easy fix to check if your account ID matches one of the people you'd work with, and not show you the ad in that case, so we'll probably fix that too. All of that is about company page ads though, which isn't what we're working on at the moment (although slightly updated designs will appear soon).

Comment: To your other points, we currently have an experiment running comparing how well showing you ads targeted based on your history versus based on what you're looking at right now. It's possible we might do some of both in the future, but we haven't made any decisions yet. More likely, we'll give you ways to tell us what you want to see (if anything), but as I said, that's outside the scope of this post.

Comment: To your last point about getting better behavior out of companies, that's a whole other issue, but people are specifically working on how to address that problem as well. It's difficult, it will take a while, and it's _definitely_ well out of the scope of discussion for this post since it's not exactly something we can fix with ad design.

Comment: So, basically I'm closing your answer as off-topic... ;) It's good product feedback though.

Comment: I'd be more worried if I saw an ad for my company that **didn't** list me among the employees I'd be working with!

Comment: @Air Your company has to nominate you to be shown as one of their "who you'll work with"s, and you have to agree to it, so you shouldn't be surprised if it doesn't show you. Also if there are more than three people on the list, it won't show you every time.

Comment: Just an attempt at humor - but that's interesting to know. :)

Comment: @BretCopeland You don't entirely surprise me, but I'm only answering the questions you specifically asked. It's not my fault you're only considering changes that have nothing to do with those questions. :-)

Comment: @DanHulme I didn't understood the first point. Can you make it normal pehleez? Agreed with the encouragement point

Answer (score 20):

I would like to share my idea. As per my little experience i have little idea. You may add icons for job details. For example there will be a job detail page where you will add all icons you need along with their abbreviation. In the job ads you will have to just add icons which will indicates the job benefits and requirements.  You can show more details of job in small place using icons, it will also helpful in responsive . I hope you understand what i want to say exactly, also i attached a test ads image.[image]

Comment: Kinda similar to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315507/4099593) suggestion. :)

Comment: Nice, but RVM would mean nothing to me.  I liked the wi-fi icon in @Bhargav's answer, and you could use $ vs $$ vs $$$ for the mid career thing.  I'm not sure for the visa thing though...

Comment: @cullub there is no means of RVM. These are separate icons which indicates different meaning like R stand for Remote, and also icons will show according to job details. If job has visa then V icon will be show. They can also use proper icons if they wants it just basic idea. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, what I was saying was that simply seeing a blue circle with an `M` inside it, as a new user to Stack Overflow, or even as someone not acquainted  with Careers, would not tell me anything.  I would not know that it stood for a mid-career job.

Comment: @Cullub A tooltip would fix that pretty easily though.

Comment: That's true.  I still like the idea of self-explanatory icons though.

Comment: They look like subway icons to me. Like, "huh, I guess the job is near the R, V, and M train lines." ... might actually be useful information in some cities.

Comment: If you want me to click your ads don't make me take out my decoder ring. Use meaningful icons so I can get it in a glance. Don't make me think!

Answer (score 18):

Show **all** tags upfront.

Right now I see, let say, `Java`, `SQL`. After I click it appears that the three other tags point to languages / technologies I'm not intimately familiar with.

Comment: Yup. Or, alternatively: show more specific tags instead. Java+SQL can be pretty much anything.

Comment: @m01 that's because just about any Java developer can do just about any Java+SQL job...

Comment: We might be able to get away with showing more tags on ads for individual jobs rather than a list of jobs. With the list, it starts to get real cluttered real fast. Also, the tags are generally set by the employers, and to be honest, a lot of the less popular tags are even less helpful nonsense. I think knowing what industry they work in would actually be more interesting and useful than more tags.

Answer (score 16):

> What factors into your decision to click or not click on an ad?

I believe there are three different color'd boxes. Orange, Blue and Yellow.

#### Orange Box

Orange seems to show me two relatively local listings and two "somewhere else in the country" listings. Not all of them are relevant.

[image: Orange Box]

For example, I keep getting [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/78286/senior-video-editor-simantel?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=large-sidebar-orange-looking). The location is somewhat close, but none of the tags are relevant (OK...I do think I know how to use [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logic), but I know nothing about design work or adobe products). The [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/101423/art-director-simantel?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=large-sidebar-orange-looking) for the same company keeps appearing too. It has no tags, so I assume it is also targeting by location. Neither of these are relevant to my skill set. The other two positions have the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag that I'm active in, but the one at Navatek has a [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) that I don't think I've ever answered a question in.

Of the 4 listed above, the only one I'd even consider clicking is the Handshake job. But, it doesn't have a note about Relocation or Remote, so in this case, I wouldn't.

#### Blue Box

This one seems to show me job near my location (which is wrong, based on the "jobs near..." line), regardless of my tag set

[image: Blue Box]

These are the two jobs I mentioned above. I'd never click on either of these jobs as displayed. I'm not qualified for either based only on the job title and tags.

#### Yellow Box

This one is targeted based on tag. I don't know if a user can have more than one associated tag, but I only ever see jobs for Python. Makes sense, as that's where I spend a majority of my time.

[image: Yellow Box]

Both of these jobs have a tag I'm skilled in and offer remote work, which I've indicated in my CV. I'd look at both of these positions. However, once I have (and I have seen the Clevertech one a ton), I won't click it again.

A way to indicate that a position isn't relevant or that I'm not interested would be helpful to me (and probably you). For me, it'd stop showing something I'm not interested in. For you, it'd give you feedback on the jobs that you could use to better target users, share with the employers, or at least use to make targeting toward single users more relevant.

> What kinds of information are most important to you?

For me, if the position isn't near my physical location, it's important that I know if they offer relocation or remote options. That does mean that remote needs to actually mean "full time telecommute position" though. If it doesn't ([and many that I seem drawn to don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273110/can-the-jobs-careers-team-explain-to-employers-the-purpose-of-the-remote-optio)) that indicator is noise.

It's also important to know the company name, job title and tags. Salary range would be nice, but it's not on enough listings yet that it may bias me when I see four listings and only one has a salary range.

> Do you have any anecdotes on how you select jobs to apply for?

I'd love to watch the "Matches" tab on Jobs. The jobs there seem to be fairly relevant. However, [I find it unuseable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312540/on-jobs-how-do-i-sort-by-most-recent-matches). The matches aren't sort-able by post date and I am sick of seeing the "most relevant" job being something that was posted weeks ago. I have no way to clear that order and the most relevant job for me is not the top job. Just scrolling through the list now, I see multiple jobs that were posted in the last week that I didn't see before because they are so far down my list.

I've also tried to set up some matches for companies I'm interested in, but that also [doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262133/how-do-i-set-up-a-job-alert-to-be-specific-to-a-company)

Instead, I go to the most recent tab, select a few options (usually "remote") and look at the most recent matches that way. It's not optimal, especially because there are two other ways that look like they would be useful if issues were fixed, but that's how I use Jobs now.

> Besides individual job listings, are there other types of ads for the job board that you would find interesting?

Personally, I wouldn't find the individual listings interesting. I get them occasionally, but all they do for me is scream "advertisement!" and I tune it out.

[image: Targeted job]

The size of this ad is larger than the orange box. The image at the top makes it larger. I think that's part of what makes it scream "advertisement!". The other thing that bothers me, is that it blends in with the main page more. The Orange, Blue and Yellow boxes have a very distinct border. This one has a thin grey border, making it seem more 'stealthy'. Finally, only one of these jobs is relevant (the first one), but even then with that [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) that I haven't answered any questions in, I don't know how relevant it actually is. It also doesn't list relocation or remote work like the other two do. I wouldn't click on it.

> Other ideas or comments?

The ability to mark a job ad as relevant or not relevant would help both sides. You'd quickly learn what I (we) like and don't like and could target jobs better. I'd get jobs that are more tuned to what I'm looking for in my next position.

I do like the simple Orange/Blue/Yellow boxes. The color changes enough to draw my attention. I think the "near me" jobs need to have a bit more focus though - just because a job is near my location doesn't mean I'm interested in it.

I'd be interested in something like the tag targeted yellow box, but for remote positions.

Comment: For the colors, if they let me make Java SO questions purple and JavaScript SO questions green, it would go a lot further by turning Java jobs purple and JavaScript jobs green. Great functionality tie in to the main site.

Comment: Nice.  Maybe for the `job not relevant to me` it could be a simple thumbs-down icon on the listing...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The changes in giving you more control are, like I said, something we want to do, but are out of scope for this topic. The blue and orange ads are exactly the same. Sometimes their header says different things, but either color can say any header. We pick what the ad is going to look like _after_ we select which jobs to show. For you, if all of the jobs are python, then we show the yellow python ad, because it's in your top 5 tags. There are nine other tags we highlight for people who have them in their top 5.

Comment: There is also an ad people in the US should see some of the time in which all of the jobs offer remote, and that fact is highlighted. The "individual" ads you're referring to are Company Page ads, and not at all what I was suggesting. However, I will point out that they do in fact perform better than the job ads we run.

Comment: I'll have to watch for that remote one. I don't recall seeing it. That is something that I'd be interested in seeing more of though.

Comment: +1 for "A way to indicate that a position isn't relevant or that I'm not interested would be helpful to me"

Comment: I didn't realize that "remote" on SO careers only means "we'll let you work from home sometimes" or perhaps even "you can do extra work at home after spending 8+ hours on our premises". If that's true, or even partially true, that kills 90% of my interest in SO jobs/careers right there. It had looked like one of the better places to hunt for full time remote positions.

Comment: @Arlie It is supposed to mean full time remote. It's not always used that way though.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Comment: The buttons (like/don't like) are not mobile-friendly, too small and too close to each other.

Comment: The principle is OK, but up/down arrows might be more stack overflowy, and allow the ad engine to be trained to individual preferences

Answer (score 10):

> What factors into your decision to click or not click on an ad?

Physical locality, or an interest in working in a specific field.

> What kinds of information are most important to you?

Is the project interesting? Is it a challenge? Does it serve some kind of greater public good?

> Do you have any anecdotes on how you select jobs to apply for?

I once chose to work in industrial instrumentation because control theory is related to chaos, and oddly enough I left that field when I found a flawed system design that was going chaotic...

> Besides individual job listings, are there other types of ads for the job board that you would find interesting?

Conferences, call for papers, academic research, or competitions having to do with machine learning or medical imaging.

> Other ideas or comments?

Something which turns me off about job postings is when they're canned. Of course that's out of your control, but I find my curiosity has limits, and I often won't return to looking at job listings for a few months.

@blagae's comment got me thinking, *what would it take to get her/his interest in a job posting*? Then I realised this was a good question for me as well. So why not incorporate a survey for users in the job section?

*What would it take for you to consider accepting a job with us*?

Comment: Conferences & calls for papers would be mightily interesting for me, because I now have no incentive to go into the Jobs section.

Comment: I agree with @blagae, The conferences and call for is really a great idea. But do you think conferences would pay money for ads? (I don't know whether the committee pays for ads)

Comment: does it matter whether they'd pay money? - include the conferences etc. as a public service - and to get people to maybe notice the job adds as well

Comment: @Bhargav Rao, I think some professional conferences would pay for ads while the academic ones likely wouldn't.

Comment: I like @Arlie Stephens idea to put them in as a public service and perhaps have a way for a job poster to piggy back on that. If I knew a company had an interest in a conference that I had an interest in then I'd be far more likely to listen to what they had to say.

Comment: Some companies sponsor conferences (at least large ones).  If they're paying to list jobs, maybe they could advertise the conferences they sponsor -- even "meet engineer E at conference C".

Answer (score 8):

I am not looking for a job.  I might interact with ads if I knew that that I was adding to the possibility of ads being relevant when I need them.

So, just a simple up/down vote and a way for me to set up my own filter would be nice.

For me personally, if I didn't know that it was remote, there would be no chance I would care about it -- so it would be nice to be able to say that.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, I like the current overall appearance. It's distinct enough to be noticeable, obviously not part of the content I'm reading or replying to, and not flashy enough to be distracting.

Second, I like having multiple suggestions.

Third, as long as your selection algorithms consistently produce terrible matches, nothing you can add will get me to click through. You've been training me quite effectively to disregard your ads, which is really quite a pity, because I'm unlikely to notice when/if you ever fix your massive mistargeting problem. (Yes, I've clicked through on a number, and not found hits.)

Finally, looking at fields you say you have, many of which are already shown

1. job title. I wish there was a way to get more precision on this!
2. location. And relocation avail. And visa sponsorship avail.
3. technologies (I wish you had tags for all the things I do!)
4. contract vs permanent. Some of us won't touch contract; others won't
   touch permanent.
5. salary range, if they give it
6. Joel test, if they give it. (If they give it, I'm more interested in
   them.)

I'm presuming there's no room for job descriptions, though if they appeared in a pop-up when I hover a mouse over it, I would kind of like that.

Then on to what I really want, and you can't get systematically:

- how hands-on is it?
- how senior is it?
- private office/tall cubes/short cubes/open office/hoteling/remote
- availability (and requirement) for business travel
- technology used, beyond just what you have tags for
- tools used (some tools are on my personal "never again" list)

For what it's worth, here's (part of) my personal filter for jobs to ignore:

1. wrong location (including wrong part of my metro area)
2. required business travel
3. managerial responsibilities
4. hotelling
5. open office
6. requires windows desktop etc.
7. pays less than I'm making
8. requires working on UI
9. employer on personal blacklist

Teasers that consistently waste my time get ignored.

Comment: with regard to location - what I judge by is an estimate of commute time from my home location, somewhat influenced by what commute technology would be relevant. radius of xxx miles is a poor approximation.  It would be possible to implement the real thing, for users who provided location and possibly commute technology preference. (Some people can't/don't drive, and that will influence location preference heavily.)

Comment: +1 for contract jobs. This is an absolute must for me and a lot of others I know.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for posting this.

It'd be nice if there was a way for companies to clarify if they are in a "we want smart people who can code, but not necessarily require experience in the language(s) we use."

One annoying thing about ads on Stack Overflow is there is no indication as to which is true:

- We want someone who has [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)[sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) experience
- We want someone who *will do* and can learn [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)[sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) (and has other programming background)

The only way to find out is to click through and try to read/parse HR-speak job postings.

Answer (score 7):

My idea: look for ideas that have already been mentioned on Meta StackExchange and have [status-deferred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/careers+status-deferred). E.g. I have requested [to manually exclude tags from being advertised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249745/245641)

Other items I'd like to see improved:

- be able to remove ads that I have reviewed and not liked
- opt out completely (maybe just for a few months), e.g. for people that have just switched the company and don't want another new job within 2 weeks

Answer (score 6):

I think more important than "how to show the ad", is to filter what ad to show.

E.g. I often see job ads for frontend developers, but my CV says that I dislike [frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend).

To make this on topic:

How about showing something like a scoring about how good the job matches the users CV. This does not have to be a number. It could be a bronce,  silver or gold badge.

Comment: That's more of a targeting issue than a design issue. If it's in your disliked CV tags, you shouldn't see anything tagged that, but I'm sure most front-end jobs don't actually include that tag. There's certainly ways we can improve on this in the future, as I said in the post, it's out of scope for this discussion.

Comment: @BretCopeland Srorry, you are right. I added my suggestion to make it more on topic.

Answer (score 6):

Another thing to add: the jobs displayed need to **not** show positions which are tagged in **technologies you hate** on your job profile.  There are some technologies that I wouldn't touch for 2x the pay, and I've added those to the job seeker profile - honor that & you'd go a long way towards making things more useful.

In addition, it would be nice to let us tell you our geographic preferences in the job seeker profiles, and filter the results by that.  For example, I'm nowhere near Seattle, but I'd not be averse to relocating.  So, since you know where I live, if I've ticked the box that says "willing to relocate" you should show me positions in Seattle.  There's noplace to tell you that on the job seeker profile, however.

Comment: We already do filter out listings which are tagged with one of your disliked CV tags, although occasionally there's a cache miss and you might still see one, but it shouldn't be common. If it is common for you, should should post it as a bug report. A problem with the current setup is that it's only literal tag matching. We might get more sophisticated about filtering in the future.

You second point is something we will indeed get to. Things are in a bit of flux behind the scenes due to unification, but when that settles down, we'll start working on it.

Neither point is about design, though.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I look forward to whatever's coming down the pike!

Answer (score 6):

First of all I want to mark jobs as "Not interesting / hide forever / ignore" which i don't want to see. I'm seeing over and over again same rubbish company ads or some jobs which is not interested with me. For example, I went to one of that companies for interview already -not on SO- and I don't want to see that job, even if I quickly ignore after I saw. It's still engaging my attention, I'm losing my time (yes seconds, stones become mountains). Disappointment is cherry on top.

Answer (score 5):

**IMO, there are/should be some rules:**

1. Don't show anything, only to show anything.
2. Treat it more responsibly, by helping both sides (user and advertiser) to come together. There is no other benefit for all involved parties by displaying ads.
3. Focus more on UX-Design. The design (colors, forms etc.) is the result of UX-Design.

**Need some users information:**
To display only relevant IT jobs (based on skills, location ...) and to match rule 1+2, you need some user information. Get infos by creating a user cookie with relevant info:

Ask the user only once in a dialog:
"Are you interested to get relevant jobs on the right side?" YES/NO

If NO: Don't bother him with these kind of advertisement. Really, don't bother him.

If Yes: Ask him in a dialog

1. Your skills and preferred technology (Programming: JAVA, C++; Consulting: ...)
2. Your preferred location (Worldwide, US, Europe ...)
3. Communication languages (English, Spanish, French, German ...)

***Store his answers in a cookie and read it each time he visits stackoverflow.***

This could be enough to give a idea of it.

@JustGoscha Thank you for your feedback regarding googlemaps. Googlemaps makes only sense and is only a solution, if the user wants localized ads.

Comment: No please no google maps, this site will get bloated for something nobody needs! Or at least nobody came for it to this site. All those things could be on the jobs page of SO not a normal question page.

Comment: Exactly.  But I like the first three rules...

Answer (score 5):

What about showing job offers **regardless** of the location? I get all my job adds from around my are, and the only data I have filled in my StackOverflow CV is that I am not looking for a job and that I don't mind to relocate.

I don't mind to relocate == I don't mind job offers in Hong Kong or New York, as long as they are what I like. However, I'm stuck with Exeter job ads, because I live nearby!

Comment: Off topic for this post, but definitely something you should expect to see in the not too distant future.

Answer (score 5):

A few thoughts:

- Use my search from the careers page to help (but allow some flexibility)
- For those of us behind a corporate proxy wall; let us specify where we are located - most of the jobs being listed to me now are in the wrong location

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to see the **Joel test results**.

I'm working in a Joel rating 5 environment - and do not want to make this experience again.

Answer (score 3):

Add little numbers to see under the ad: how many unique users clicked the add, how many applied, how many got response from the company.

Answer (score 3):

More of a re-design to [@Ritzgy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315505/help-us-redesign-job-ads/315533#315533).

[image: job listing]

Instead of having the date both up top *and* below, I replaced the one below with symbols signifying - wait, can't you tell what they mean?

That's the point.  Easy for everyone to understand.  This job is located in Jakarta, Indonesia, but this position is remote (hence the wifi symbol).  It is medium pay grade, so they're probably looking for a mid-experienced dev.  See that rectangle with a line through it, and a circle in the middle?  That's the passport symbol.  That would signify that if you have to move to this country to be able to work there, they'd sponsor the visa. <sub>(Thanks, @Bret Copeland)</sub>

If It's not remote, (obviously), we'll remove the wifi symbol, but if they offer monetary support for moving, we could add a house symbol:
[image: house]

...And add different icons based on different criteria.

Comment: Visa sponsorship means that the company will sponsor a [visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_(document)) for a foreign person to be able to live and work in the country of the company. It has nothing to do with Visa, the company that facilitates credit cards.

Comment: HAHA!! ... and I used the credit card symbol :D

Comment: Fixed it.  I used the passport symbol instead.

Comment: Not so obvious: I thought the wifi symbol meant one was working _with_ wifi. The rectangle with circle suggests a camera to me. So my first guess is that the product is a camera that communicates with its home base by wifi. Farther confirmed by the location, which I associate with producing tech toys etc. A bit surprised by no mention of lower level languages or protocols, so my best guess is that it's a UI job in that tech space.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok, thanks.  What about if the wifi, $$, and box icons were a little smaller and to the right, to separate them from the location?  Or maybe rows with icon and text? ...

Comment: Or better, just have a tooltip for each of the icons.

Comment: I like the house. Maybe [give it an arrow](https://storify.com/cmgnationalnews/hillvetica-hillary-bold-font) to indicate moving?

Comment: My take on these icons: 1.) Remote/Wifi. I mean it is the official wifi symbol after all. I think like you said a house would be more meaningful. 2.)We pay you  money, instead of cheeseburgers. 3.) Something that suspiciously looks like flat pokeball.  (( Maybe we should move away from icons and just make it text tags instead. ))

Comment: @cullub I think part of my problem is that the symbols somehow didn't look like standard boiler plate associated with all ads. Having them smaller and slightly separated would probably help - but I can't look at it "cold" a second time - it's much easier to understand anything once you already know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the side bar, I'd like to be able to click an "X" to make certain ads go away.

On the job detail page I'd like to be able to upvote, downvote, ask questions, and comment on ads.

Make the ads more relevant or allow me to vote on how relevant the ad is for me. For instance, [this ad](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/104472/full-stack-software-engineer-synthetics-new-relic?searchTerm=python&offset=2&distanceunits=Miles&location=arizona&range=20) shows up because I'm interested in python. However, after clicking I found this line,

> (but, to be honest, we mainly use Java).

This wastes my time because they tagged it with python even though they are a Java shop.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the link `More jobs near city-name` because it force me to change page and it is the only way to see the complete list of job positions.

I think that the box should work as a slideshow. Following this approach I could search all job descriptions using, for example, two arrow buttons.

The link `More jobs near city-name` could be replaced with something like `Search your job`.

Comment: ...Or else, it could just open a pop-up, or new tab with the jobs.

Comment: Yea, could be a good idea

Answer (score 2):

1. Make use of Your Recent Searches while giving options.
   [image]
2. Get some preferences from us and save. Many people want some preferences while showing job Ads if they are wiling to change.

   - Allows Remote  (Do not combine with Location)
   - Offers Relocation
   - Offers Visa Sponsorship
   - Job located in Circumference of 20km-100km
   - Job Type
   - Job Keywords and tags

[image]

Comment: Are these recent searches searches on SO or on the jobs site?

Comment: @ http://stackoverflow.com/jobs See right sidebar.

Comment: Do you not see a problem with displaying people's job searches on a site they're most likely to use at work?

Comment: This are `Ads`. So Ads which are more promising should be shown. You might be aware that google and fb shows Ads of shopping those you see while shopping online.

Comment: But *this* is *SO*.  We don't have to be like google.  Or anyone else.  We were created because the world needed something *different*.

Comment: @cullub: I am just suggesting that if job ads shown related to recent searches (if person is searching so that means looking for specific job type) that will be good tool for people to get correct/good job.

Comment: As unification of the Careers job board with Stack Overflow settles down, you can expect to see more preferences which will affect ads, but for now, it's not something we can fix with design.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if you could turn job ads off completely and then have them replaced with something more relevant, say you set in your profile you are not interested in a job.

Answer (score 1):

What about making information included in the ads customizable by the users?     Just like adding or even filtering tags describing properties I'm interested in. For example `[location]`, `[is_remote]`, `[technologies]`,`[position]`, etc.  Sounds like... expansion and integration of/with careers "interested in" field.

Answer (score 1):

**I just want more jobs to choose in my unpopular district.**

It seems that you are designing the UI for district that has many jobs. But my problem is totally different: There are too few jobs in SO job board in my district, Hong Kong. By the time I was typing this, there were only *2 jobs* in my district. In Hong Kong, it is very difficult to find good software jobs. Ordinary job boards are full of rubbish, it is extremely difficult to find good software jobs in those job boards. Good job boards like SO job board contain only a few jobs. I have search jobs for years and feel hopeless.

> What factors into your decision to click or not click on an ad?

I clicked on every link in the job ads because there were too few links, I even remembered that I have clicked the link or not.

Maybe not only Hong Kong is experiencing this problem, but also many other districts.

Comment: Certainly a problem, but sadly not one that we're going to be able to fix with a redesigned ad, so it's a bit out of scope. The regions with lots of jobs on our site are a reflection of the regions we have sales teams dedicated to (namely, North America and Western Europe). I think the best we can do in the short term is emphasize the jobs which offer remote, relocation, and visa sponsorship. And perhaps in the future, we'll show you job ads less frequently if there's not a great match.

Comment: @BretCopeland Maybe you need to show ads to employers saying "be one of X companies shown to the N people in region R", if X is small and N is large.  Probably not within your remit, but worth passing along.

Answer (score 1):

I would preposition the "Asked: Today, Viewed: 51 Times, Active: Today" section somewhere else (Perhaps right above the question). Then that would move the jobs posting up. That would kill two birds with one stone because the question metadata would be closer to the question, increasing relativity and the job posting will have less interference by not being sandwiched between question related content. Another thing I would do it make each job posting have a widescreen-card layout to represent independency from one another.

Comment: If you're interested in discussing moving the "Asked: Today, Viewed: 51 Times, Active: Today" section, you should probably post it as a separate question, probably on MSE. I think it's going to be a bit too buried here.

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking moving that section was somewhat associated with the job section because it would then move up but I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I usually see repeated advertisement from 2 or 3 companies daily. Whenever I try to go through that company portal (just in case), I came to know that the company is not hiring or it is not supporting such colleges from I am. Such kind of short listing for showing the jobs must be filtered.

Answer (score 1):

Well then there's people like me, who think the ad's show great opportunities, but I'm barely past 18 and still in high school. No sane job would even look at me, and frankly I don't blame them one bit, but I can't opt out of them.

My opinion on them aesthetically is that it's very hard to pick them out while doing something, you having to circle one in a picture says a lot.

Comment: To be fair, the circling in the screenshot is to just make it clear which part of the page we're talking about vs the leaderboard ad up top or other ads we serve.

Comment: Mm, fair enough. But there should be a way to differentiate between your ad's and normal ad's.

Comment: Honest question: why? What sort of distinction are you hoping to see? Would you be more inclined to pay attention to our job ads (on behalf of companies that are hiring) over curated generally dev-relevant ads, and if so, how do you perceive the two ad types to be different?

Comment: I think most people are more willing to see an ad they know this site supports, instead of seeing it as an intrusion, it's more of an actual opportunity. Also, if I'm curious and want to poke around more about one of the 'job opportunities' i generally trust the link more, that it won't do anything too obnoxious or trap me on its page, exploit my cookies etc. People spend hours and lots of mental effort on this site, so I imagine they'll trust something more if they see you guys believe it to be useful to us.

Comment: Sounds fair enough. Thanks. :) For what it's worth, our ad sales team works hard to filter out/reject anything that's obviously irrelevant. We take this pretty seriously.

Answer (score 0):

When I see a job posted that I'm very interested in, it would be nice to be able to flag the ad to be sent to my inbox or list of favorites job posts. I can't look at it immediately at work, and it's just left to luck if I find it again when I'm home. It would be nice if it were waiting for me to read about and possibly apply for all at my leisure away from the workplace.

Answer (score -3):

**Ideas:**

1. Like the idea of SO/SE-coworkers (on job page)
2. Do not like the idea of numbers like clicked ad, ...
3. Salary I think is not required as most job offers does not include concrete numbers and as said before salary is not the most important information for lot of people

**Design:**

- 3 to 5 ads as "list" like now
- ads should be clearly separated for example by cards like shown Rizky

Comment: There need not be concrete numbers to make salary information relevant to many (including myself). A range, as some do, is plenty enough to see if we (the company and I) have anything to discus. Offering $60-80k in San Francisco would amount to living in a cardboard box; no need to waste time with that...

Answer (score -7):

Some even more specific, friendly duty briefing.

```
Web Designer
"We need a fresh-mint new look in our site".
```

Or revealing a little abstract of the projects they need help: Enough to be clear, but also to not reveal good ideas for competition to copy.

```
Software developer
"More hands to our revolution and publicity campaigns".
```

In conclussion, a mixture of both: A valuable slogan, subtle and demanding.

**BONUS**: Why don't you just guys format job titles like many other valid StackOverflow entries:

```
Why our servers are starving for more front-end code?
```

or

```
#Error: More support is required (WxWidgets, Python).
```

Why don't you just put a little of offers, requirements and stuff in disguise inside some site common entries (but pasive: let's say 1 offer every 50 or 100 questions a user clicks and BOOM!...I mean: "Hey that's not an answer, that's a job offer". ).

How about offering some reputation for sharing the available work space in user's social sites and stuff by referring its publisher once employee has been accepted and dude really worth being recruited? Not many: some 15-20 would be nice.

Proposal overviews have the common StackExchange format, but not the main start page (Careers). Featured jobs take a minimum space, why not a whole row? I'm not an expert, but that section doesn't look very funny for appliance...does it?

Comment: I agree that a plain job title isn't very informative, but I expect most "job slogans" to be similarly uninformative.

Comment: I didn't meant to say a slogan, but more like a briefy overview of their activities and projects, but I suppose that revealing their real needs is a vulnerable point that competition may take advantage

Comment: Job summary in 10 words, yes. Not many people realize, you can tell a lot about the company by how they use these 10 words.

Comment: They should offer a job to successfully do that.

Answer (score -12):

How about adding some kind of social proof to the listing? e.g.

> 5 devs like you checked out this listing.

I also like the idea of adding "who you'll be colleagues with", even if it's only a number, e.g.

> 4 Stack Overflow users work here

... or even a cumulative rep score for all SO users who work there. Or maybe better yet, average (total SO rep / total # employees), which might work as a proxy for dev-friendliness.

Comment: Maybe users with 200 rep?  I can see a company asking all its employees to create an account, and you'd only want to count accounts with some non-association-bonus activity.

Comment: Meh. No.  I don't want to see social stuff in ads.

Comment: lol the minute someone says social on this site mass downvotes happen.

Comment: I shoulda used a different word huh @JonH

Comment: You heard it here first - Sam wants both social things on SO and reducing employees to numbers. kappa

Comment: It's a great idea indeed! Add how many people applied, and what their aggregated profile is, so much to work out, but it should boost applicant's interest.

Comment: Telling people that X help vampires ^H^H^H Stack Overflow users work for a particular company is not really flattering when you think of it.