# Jobs is not saving Location criteria when selecting "Most Recent" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I want to click on the "Most Recent" tab after I perform a search where I specify a keyword and the option to work remotely. When I do so, the "Remote" option is ignored on the Most Recent tab.

---

To replicate my bug, perform the following steps:

- Search for "Python" in the keywords field. Should return this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=Python) and roughly 630 jobs at the time of this post.
- In the location box, select "Allows Remote" and click search. Should return this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=Python&allowsremote=true) with about 67 jobs at the time of this post.

At this point it is on the "Relevance" tab. Since this tab is [sorted poorly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312540/on-jobs-how-do-i-sort-by-most-recent-matches) and I see that there are newer jobs further down the page, I want to sort by "Most Recent".

- Click on the "Most Recent" tab. It shows approximately 630 results (the same as it did when "Remote" wasn't selected).

---

The keyword utilized isn't important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report! There seems to have been a knot of recent bugs related to those buttons. I've completely rewritten the query-string-templating code that was to blame. Your bug, and all the bugs like it, should be fixed now.