# After applying to a position, don't show that position as featured in Jobs listing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Some positions are featured and hold the first listing when matches are shown. However, that featured position will still display a job that I've applied to.

In this case, the featured position did it's job. I found something that looked interesting. It shouldn't show up as featured at this point, because it is no longer relevant that I see the position.

This appears on both the ([unordered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312540/on-jobs-how-do-i-sort-by-most-recent-matches)) matches tab and the most recent tab.

#### Request

If I applied to a position, don't show that specific position in the "featured" first slot on the job search results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the request, this is now implemented; we'll never show a featured job at the top if you've already applied to it.