# Remember my sort order on Jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Recently, (in the last day?) Jobs introduces a sort drop down on some - but not all - searches.

[image: Sort Options]

This option doesn't appear on something like ["Remote Only"](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?allowsremote=True&rs=1) searches. With that search, I am only presented with "most recent". However, a job search that is ["Remote Only and salaries over 100K"](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=salary%3A100001&allowsremote=True&rs=1) provides both options.

The current default is "relevance". [This is NOT what I want.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312540/on-jobs-how-do-i-sort-by-most-recent-matches) It means I miss postings that I care to see.

I want to see the most recent matches for what ever query I run. I also want to see those results without needing to adjust the sort order every time I run my search.

Request: Remember my sort order so that future searches will order results in the order **I** want, not the order you think I want.

Comment: I posted this earlier: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327543/distance-not-saved-across-paging-in-jobs not the same as yours but similar in nature.  It's a tad bit confusing what is updated vs what isn't as well as what should be carried over after postbacks.