# Distance not saved across paging in jobs

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

When you do a search for jobs and change the distance value it does not maintain its state across paging.

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

- Change the distance from 20 miles to 50 miles
- Page to the 2nd page

**Note:** This happens whether or not you click search and it also happens even if you enter a location.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to hit Search again... Changing anything in that form and changing the page will not cause the updated fields to be used. Hitting search submits the form and updates the querystring that the pager links rely upon.

Comment: The UX needs to relay this information in a better way.  For instance, any edit of a filter should add a new class to the button changing its color or appearance.  You guys keep going around these issues.  It would help visually see what I need to do when I change a filter.

Comment: *nothing* on that form updates immediately. Why would you assume otherwise, the page doesn't update in any way.

Comment: Dean, however you should lead your user to see that changing a filter requires a re-"search".  Which currently you guys don't do, in fact...it doesn't save it even if you click search try it out.  I just typed in "Javascript" and set the miles to 50.  As soon as I click "Search" it goes back to 20.

Comment: Admittedly that is confusing, we don't persist range if you don't enter a location. It's not used unless you enter one. Search UX is in the process of a large overhaul. 6 - 8 weeks I guess.

Comment: Confusing to say the least.  This is not the first time I mentioned this.  I hope you see my point from a real world end user.

Comment: It also doesn't work if you actually enter a city / location - try it out yourself.

Comment: Gah, seriously. I've fixed this bug like a 1000 times already and it keeps regressing. Time to get a big beating stick out and knock it into shape :/

Comment: I have a few more lined up for you I'll post soon :-| ...

Comment: @DeanWard, while nothing in the *form* updates the page immediately, just below it if you select the dropdown for "relevance" it *does* update immediately. That makes it confusing too. [Especially when that particular field isn't saved either.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325921/remember-my-sort-order-on-jobs)

Comment: @JonH fixed that regression, but I'll leave the by-design on the tag (because, well, it is, despite being bad UX). We're looking into search UX for jobs, there'll be new bits soon.