# Clicking arrow on "Sort by" drop down doesn't do anything in Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The redesigned "Sort by" drop down doesn't work in Firefox 48.0.2 in Windows 10, if I click on the arrow. Instead, it just focuses on the widget. I have to click on the text to get the options to appear.

Demo:

[image: Drop down not working]

This makes the fact that [sort order isn't remembered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325921/remember-my-sort-order-on-jobs) even more annoying.

Comment: Thanks for reporting that. Fix should be deployed in few hours.