# My Job Matches don't make sense

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm confused by what I'm seeing as my highest matches on Jobs. Previous [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312543/189134) explain these results are from personalized predictions based on personalized prediction data and tags in my CV. Yet, my top matches to not match my skill set.

Can someone explain why I'm seeing some of these results?

My top (non-featured) result is:

- [Experienced C++ developer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/126978/experienced-c-plus-plus-developer-metova-inc?offset=0&sort=i). This has the following tags: [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile), [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json)

I am not a c++ developer. It is not on my first page of [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy?tab=tags). [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) does appear on my first list of tags, but I only have a score of 17 in it (versus, much higher scores on other tags).

The second result I have is:

- [Big Data DevOps Engineer (100% Remote but must be between UTC-2 and UTC+7)](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/126469/big-data-devops-engineer-100-remote-but-must-be-hotjar?offset=1&sort=i). This has the following tags: [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services), [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx) [hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop)

This time it at least has [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (my highest tag score). But, the other technologies are not something I'm involved in. Additionally, the requirement for timezone doesn't fall within my location. To be fair, I don't think Stack Exchange asks for this information from employers, but it still is a job I can't meet the requirements of due to location.

Next:

- [Senior Full Stack Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/127447/senior-full-stack-developer-cb-insights?offset=3&sort=i) with these tags: [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [nosql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql).

This job has a salary range that meets the criteria I've set. It also has several tags I have a score in (python, javascript and mysql). So far, this looks like the best match of the top three. It does not offer the remote working ability of the first two though. However, the option in my preference is labeled: "Willing to work remotely" not "Only remote", so I can understand it meeting my matches. This was also posted 3 hours ago - versus the 1 week and 2 week old posts from the above two.

Next we come to:

- [Healthcare Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/127144/healthcare-developer-commvault?offset=4&sort=i) with these tags: [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [dicom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dicom), [pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pac), [imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imaging), [hl7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7)

Again, I'm not a c++ developer, and I don't know what those other tags are.

Finishing off the top 5:

- [Technical Services Engineer (Calling all Senior Developers/DevOps backgrounds)](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/120715/technical-services-engineer-calling-all-senior-mongodb?offset=5&sort=i) with tags: [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database), [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking)

I have tag score in a few of these. It's also a remote position. The posting is also only 3 hours old.

---

In the top five postings, I see two that should be ranked higher in my matches. I see at least one that is completely unrelated (the Healthcare Developer one) and two that I can see relevance, but I'd consider low. As I scroll down the listings, the jobs I'd consider "good" are interspersed with jobs that I don't have any qualifications for due to used technology.

In my preferences, I do not have tech I don't want to work with listed.

Can someone explain how these matches are determined and what I can do to get better matches?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For matching, there are quite a few factors which come into play, most of which can be influenced by updating your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current):

- Your location

  - including your preferred locations ("Where you'd like to work") and your remote preference ("Willing to work remotely")
- Your [personalized prediction data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data)

  - includes the tags of the questions you've viewed in the last month on Stack Overflow
- The novelty of the job (how recently it was posted)
- The titles and tags of the work/education items in your [developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current)
- Your (dis)liked tags
- Your visa preferences
- Your seniority preferences
- Your developer type preferences
- Your industry preferences
- Your salary preferences

The score (hence the rank) of each job in the list is determined using a [linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) of transforms of these factors. It looks pretty much like this:

```
score = weights.LikedTags * squaredLikedTagsRank
      - weights.Dist * logDistance
      + weights.Seniority * (seniorityMatch ? 1 : 0)
      [...]
```

The jobs are then ranked by descending score.

---

**In your specific case,** a few things that are relevant:

- Your Stack Overflow top tags are *not* currently part of the factors that come into play for matching. The rationale is that they don't necessarily are the tags you want to work with in the future.
- However, the "Liked tags" in your match preferences, as well as the tags of the questions you recently viewed on Stack Overflow *do* come into play.
- Some jobs target specific tech ecosystems. For instance, even though its tags don't include [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), one of the jobs near the top of your list of matches targets the "Python (web)" stack explicitly. Targeted tech ecosystems are chosen by employers (we also help them with suggestions), and are not publicly visible.
- Jobs posted recently are ranked higher. We have plans to make this smarter by also looking at the date when you last visited Stack Overflow Jobs, so that we prioritize jobs you haven't seen yet.
- Check whether you have disabled your [personalized predictions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data). Enabling them can significantly improve the relevance of job matches.

That being said, even though 4 out of 5 jobs in the top of your list target a tag you seem to be interested in ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)), the matches are not perfect, and we're working on making them better.

It seems like you have already filled all the relevant information in your matching preferences, so I don't see anything more you can do here.

In order to further filter your results, you can do a search by keyword or by tag. For instance if you [search for the python tag](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&tl=python), the resulting list of job will *exclusively* contain [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) jobs, and will be sorted so that the best matching jobs are near the top.

Comment: Thanks for the detail! I didn't know just viewing a question impacted the job matches. The explanation about the difference between top tags on SO and Liked tags in jobs makes sense too, but wasn't a connection I'd made before.