# When I use one of my most recent searches, display jobs by newest first

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I am a fan of the indicator on my recent job searches that shows if there is something new in that search filter.

[image: New Jobs!]

*<sup>Hooray! New Jobs!</sup>*

---

However, it doesn't work as I'd expect. When you click the search the results are returned with the "Matches" filter selected by default. I've brought this up [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312540/on-jobs-how-do-i-sort-by-most-recent-matches), but the 'matches' don't sort by newest first. In fact, they can have weeks old job posts over newer posts.

If I click on the "remote jobs" link on my post, the first "new" post is 5 listings down. The other two don't appear on my first page of results.

Previous [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312543/189134) have [explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336931/189134) that "Matches" takes into account how recently a job was posted, but doesn't sort by posting date.

---

#### Feature Request

I'd like to request that when I click on of my recent job searches it load the results with the "Sort by" set to "Newest". Since the widget is showing me that there are new results, it makes sense that I should be *seeing* those new results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! The string now points to the newest sort. You should see the changes on prod.