# Suggesting improvements for the Stack Overflow careers suggestion letter

Tags: bug, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

I've just received this today:

[image]

Stack Overflow Careers has all my CV information, but somehow suggests an Android Developer position for me which I have never done as a full time job. I think that the algorithm can be improved to find better matches by parsing my CV.

There is an interesting point: I've answered some Android questions in the past (several years ago), but I haven't touched the topic since. Several days ago I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359228/getting-width-of-a-large-bitmap-gives-nullpointerexception-in-android/45359270#45359270) which had the Android tag so it might explain this e-mail, but I think it is not that hard to correlate my data with jobs and conclude that I worked on Android as a non-full-time job in the past but I am not any more.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336851/my-job-matches-dont-make-sense

Comment: "have never done as a full time job" should not really disqualify this offer from consideration. There's a first time for everything.

Comment: Indeed but this is a "we really like this job for you" suggestion. I'd expect something like that to really stand out (since this is the **first ever** job suggestion that is mailed to me by SO).

Answer (score 1):

We are currently working on improvements to this email, one of which is to stop highlighting jobs which have a certain tag in their title (here [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)) unless you explicitly stated you like this tag in your [job preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current).

This update should prevent Android jobs to be recommended to you in the future. We plan to roll it out asap, most likely next week.

Thank you for your report!