# How are Recommended Jobs Picked?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

How are Recommended Jobs picked? the text underneath the recommended jobs I recieve reads:

> Based on your experience, interests, and preferences

Here are mine just from a few minutes ago:
[image]

I really only get web development things like `Django`, but I've only ever answered one [`Django` Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499196/convert-django-queryset-to-pandas-dataframe-and-maintain-column-order/44501041#44501041) and that was due to it having the tag of `pandas` (which I do want to work with):

[image]

So how are these "recommendations" created? Machine Learning, tags involved in, or just "force-feed"? and how do I get the system to start giving me relevant jobs? Or must I continuously add `django`, `flask`, `etc.....` to tech i don't want to work with?

Answer (score 3):

The recommended jobs on your profile (and on your Developer Story) are chosen by our *job matching algorithm*.

**For more details, see [this answer, with details about the algorithm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336931/1370722).**

Currently, the only item of your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) which acts as a *hard filter* is the "disliked tags". You will never be recommended a job which has a tag that you marked as "disliked".

We have plans to change this, so that *all the job preferences* act as hard filters for job recommendations (on your profile / Developer Story). This means that if you put [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in your liked tags, *only* jobs which have either the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag or the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag will be recommended to you. This will ship in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: do you have search history as one of your [features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection)? I feel like that would be very accurate. I skip every `django` question in review queues (because I don't know anything) and never search for it. I'm just guessing, but that might be a very significant predictor if you could quantify it.  Ya'll sit on some hefty data and you could really provide a ground-breaking job-site experience! I'm pulling for this to get better in the next 2̶ ̶y̶e̶a̶r̶s̶  6-8 weeks ;)

Comment: @MattR In the quoted answer it's said that https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data is used, but I didn't see any mention of skiped tags, it could be a good addition indeed.