# Right align job post time stamp again

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

A recent change to jobs shifted where the time stamp of a job posting is located. Previously, it was right aligned in the search results so that it was easy to scan the postings for what is and isn't new.

I would quickly scan my matches page for anything new, [because the "Matches" sort order can't put the newest items at the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312540/189134)...

Now that isn't easy to do.

Please right align these time stamps again

[image: Proposed Right align]

Compare that to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TNKV.png) in my previous post, and you can see how much easier it is to scan the timestamps when they are all right aligned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion.  We have now implemented it:

[image: Job list with dates floated right]